# Can I skip the init method in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go, init

I run unit tests in debug mode in a large project. However, this project references too many libs, which causes me to execute the init functions of these libs first when executing a single test. This takes a lot of time, so I'm hoping there's a way to skip the init function.

I didn't find anything to try.

Comment: To expand on the @icza's answer: the key thing to understand is that the `init` functions are like "constructors for packages", and because of this, you cannot expect a package to work properly until it wan't properly "brought to life" by its constructor. A good example to think about is some global (but unexported) `map` which various bits of the package's code use, and they all expect that map to exist (that is, created by a call to `make`) by the time that code runs.…

Comment: …That said, many seasoned Go devs advise to write packages in a way for them to not have any complex global state and provide certain exported functions which allow creating "something" representing the package's functionality and containing all the required state; all the relevant code is then made in the form of methods on such objects. But sometimes this approach may not be as sound or useful as it sounds, and there also exists legacy code.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't. Package `init()` functions must run before you can use anything from packages, else there's no guarantee they can run correctly, without panicking.

The packages themselves must support this e.g. via environment variables or any other means; or they may provide non-default init functions that must be called manually.

Comment: Thanks. I added environment variables to some init methods. This works.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use [Testing](https://pkg.go.dev/testing@master#Testing) function (Go 1.21+) to detect test mode and skip some code in `init()` (if you can change this code):

> Testing reports whether the current code is being run in a test. This
> will report true in programs created by "go test", false in programs
> created by "go build".